# What happens when operator is >,+ and two operands are unsigned int, char

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned int n = 10;
    char m = -1;
    if (m < n)
        printf("m < n\n");
    else
        printf("m > n\n");
    printf("m + n = %u\n", m + n);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code in MinGW64 on windows. It prints "m > n","m + n = 9"
I can't understand why "m + n = 9" and "m > n".

Comment: `char` is not guaranteed to be signed.  You likely have an unsigned `char` type, so -1 is really 255.

Comment: @Jason In this specific case the signedness doesn't matter. `unsigned char` should give the same result `m > n`. As would `signed char`.

Comment: @Lundin, you are correct. That is very not intuitive.

Comment: @ikegami In post/edit history. But I guess there's a specific issue in this question, `unsigned char` gives value 0xFF but `signed char` 0xFFFFFFFF because in the former case the sign conversion happens upon assignment and in the latter case upon implicit promotion.

Comment: I added the "is char signed" canonical dupe to the duplicate list too, since it does matter for the 9 vs 256 result.

Comment: It is not critical here, but if `m < n` is false, the condition is `m >= n`, not `m > n`.

Comment: The TL;DR: If `char` is signed it gets value -1, then in `m < n` the usual arithmetic conversions convert it to 0xFFFFFFFF. m + n turns into 4294967295 + 10. If `char` is unsigned it gets value 255 (as per modulo UCHAR_MAX+1), 255 > 10, 255 + 10 = 265.

Comment: @Jason: If `char` were unsigned and `m` were 255, `m+n` would be 265, not 9.

Comment: flywen, To full-range compare these potentially mixed signed types for `<`, use `m < 0 || m < n`.

Answer (score 2):

> I can't understand why "m + n = 9" and "m > n".

You can only compare compatible integers so `char` is being converted to `unsigned int` and its value is (assuming 32 bits integers and two complement negative integers) `0xffffffff` which is much more than `10`.

When you add char is converted to unsigned int and added. Two complements addition of such converted negative number gives the correct value (it acts like substraction). More information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: @EricPostpischil right. Corrected